# can't enable prompt color in bash terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I can't enable prompt color in my terminal (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).

Here's my `.bashrc`:

```
force_color_prompt=yes
export LANGUAGE='en_US.UTF-8 git'

export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
#export HISTSIZE=100000
#export HISTFILESIZE=100000

# Eternal bash history.
# ---------------------
# Undocumented feature which sets the size to "unlimited".
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457233/unlimited-bash-history
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%F %T] "
# Change the file location because certain bash sessions truncate .bash_history file upon close.
# http://superuser.com/questions/575479/bash-history-truncated-to-500-lines-on-each-login
export HISTFILE=~/.bash_eternal_history
# Force prompt to write history after every command.
# http://superuser.com/questions/20900/bash-history-loss
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
# #########

# Some example functions
# function settitle() { echo -ne "\e]2;$@\a\e]1;$@\a"; }
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/louisro/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/louisro/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

export NVM_DIR="/home/louisro/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: can you please [edit] your question including the output of  `echo $PS1`?

Comment: It seems there is a lot of stuff missing from the default ~/.bashrc file here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will enable color and will also enable color for some output such as for the output of make and ls.

```bash
# Commented out, don't overwrite xterm -T "title" -n "icontitle" by default.
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*)
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes
if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=yes
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*)
        PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -l'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

make()
{
    /usr/bin/make "$@" 2>&1 | sed -E -e "s/error/ $(echo -e "\\033[31m" ERROR "\\033[0m"/g)"   -e "s/warning/ $(echo -e "\\033[0;33m" WARNING "\\033[0m"/g)"
    return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
}
```

Source your `~/.bashrc` file to apply the changes:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess, you don't have set a colour to your prompt. You can do this with the following syntax:
`\e[x;ym $PS1 \e[m`

```
\e[ : Start colour scheme.
x;y : Colour pair to use (x;y)
$PS1 : Your shell prompt variable.
\e[m : Stop colour scheme.
```

To set a red colour prompt, type the following command:

```
export PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m "
```

add it to your `.bashrc` to make it permanent.

---

Here is a list of available colours:

```
Colour  Code
Black   0;30
Blue    0;34
Green   0;32
Cyan    0;36
Red     0;31
Purple  0;35
Brown   0;33
Blue    0;34
Green   0;32
Cyan    0;36
Red     0;31
Purple  0;35
Brown   0;33
```

Note: You need to replace digit 0 with 1 to get light colour version. refer to [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/) for more info. You may also take a look at this [very good german explanation](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bash/Prompt)

Comment: actually it doesn't work, the commands overwrite the prompt

Comment: you can replace the `\u@\h \W` part with a combination you want to use in your prompt. See [This tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) for more info about the special charachters

Comment: ok can you tell me the command so that it doesn't overwrite ?

Comment: yes, if you tell me how your prompt looked before

Comment: ha yes, it was my username, the whole path where I am (pwd) and the dollar

Comment: then use `export PS1="\e[0;31m\u \w\$ \e[m "` this will result in `username pwd$`.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work well, the cursor is in the middle of the text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30583/discussion-between-wayne-yux-and-louis).

Comment: that's ok I found a way to restore to the default bashrc and to make my own command. Thanks for your precious help Wayne, I am so happy to work with colored prompt now.